# How to change a TextView width Dynamically

Tags: android

I have a TextView1, buttons1 and buttons2 Horizontally. 
When Button2 click Button1 is invisible.
When Button1 is invisible, I need to increase the width of the textview to cover the space created when button1 is invisible and vice versa.
Can Please anybody help How can I change the Textview width dynamically.

NB: Textview tv.setWidth(pix) is not working. when I tried to find the value of tv.getWidth() gives always zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="odp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="odp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="odp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
</LinearLayout>`you can use weight for three element and button1.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

Comment: Hi Helal,  I am using View.GONE method. There is no problem. I want to increase the width of the Textview when Button1 is GONE.

Comment: You can use weight 1 for each TextView1, buttons1 and buttons2.If you use weight then width of these three element should be 0dp

Answer (score 2):

Please try to use GONE instead of using INVISIBLE. When using INVISIBLE even though you can't see it, it still takes a space.

Comment: Hi Marcin,  I am using View.GONE method. There is no problem at all to here. I am facing problem to increase the width of the Textview when Button1 is GONE.

Comment: In your xml file make sure you set width of the textview to 'wrap content' then try to change the width of it using setWidth method

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your widgets in a `RelativeLayout` and then check. You will be able to bring your `textview` on top of your `button` if it is invisble. You cant do this if you are using `LinearLayout` because it sets widgets horizontaly or verticaly and does not overlap.